# If $f \in L^{1}$, can we choose a continuous function $g$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

I know $C_{c}(X)$ is dense in $L^{1}$, so if we have $f \in L^{1}$, we can get $g_{n}(x) \to f$, so that we can get $limits_{n \to +\infty}g_{n}(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere. Then, can we choose a continuous function $g$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Not necessarily, e.g. $f=\mathbf1_{[0,1]}$

Comment: Easier puzzle:  if $f$ is continuous everywhere except at one point does that imply that it is a.e equal to a continuous function.  [Word play really.]

Comment: For an example where there is no function $g$ which is continuous a.e. and equal to $f$ a.e.: take an enumeration $r_1, r_2, \ldots$ of the rationals, and set $f := \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \chi_{[r_n, r_n + 2^{-n}]}$.  Then $f$ is unbounded on any interval (and remains so after modification on a measure zero subset), while a continuous function is of course locally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

No, we generally can't do that. At least not on the entire set, as mentioned in the comments. But under some mild conditions on $X$ and the measure $\mu$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose an $\epsilon$ "large enough" closed subset $M$ and a function $g:M \to \mathbb R$ such that $g$ is continuous on $M$ (but not on $X$!) and $g=f$ on $M$. By $\epsilon$ large enough, we mean that $\mu(M^c) \le \epsilon $.

See Lusin's theorem for example here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem#General_form